# Authenticate via OAuth with a third-party service?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, oauth

I have a bit of an issue, unfortunately.

I need to integrate a third-party service within my application, and that services requires all user to authenticate via Google OAuth (as it uses Google related services)

The problem is, when signup is completed it redirects to a URL similar to

```
https://ab.cdef.gh.ik.lm?code=examplecode
```

I tried adding `ab.cdef.gh.ik.lm` as a URL Scheme to my app but it didn't work.

The problem stems from Google no longer allowing embedded browsers to authenticate, and I need to use an `SFSafariViewController`. However, due to limitations in `SFSafariViewController`, I cannot obtain the current URL and thus monitor when it reaches the `ab.cdef.gh.ik.lm` page.

Am I out of luck, or is there a way I could handle this authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I cannot change the redirect parameter

Comment: Try [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift), it lets you use SFSafariViewController